# How to use the equivalent SQL with sub query and where clause in SSAS MDX Cube to create a measure?

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I'm trying to "convert" a SQL query to SSAS MDX expression to create a measure in SSAS Multidimensional existent cube.

In SQL I have the table below:

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | Step | StepSequence | StepDate | StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2_Saw | 2 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 5_Varnish | 5 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 6_Packing | 6 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 5_Varnish | 5 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 6_Packing | 6 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 03/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2_Saw | 2 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 05/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 05/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |

In SQL running the query ( provided by Dale in other question specific to SQL ) below:

```
select Step
    , sum(StepTimeinDays) as SumofStepTimeinDays
from dbo.build_process t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.build_process t2
    where t1.ProductCode = t2.ProductCode and t1.OperatorName = t2.OperatorName
    and t2.Step = '2_Saw'
)
group by Step
order by Step asc;
```

The return filter the table only with "2_Saw" present:

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | Step | StepSequence | StepDate | StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 0 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 1 | 02/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2_Saw | 2 | 02/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 3 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 4_Paint | 4 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 5_Varnish | 5 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 6_Packing | 6 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 0_Start | 0 | 03/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 1_Material | 1 | 03/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2_Saw | 2 | 04/05/2019 | 0 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 3_Build | 3 | 04/05/2019 | 1 |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 4_Paint | 4 | 05/05/2019 | 1 |

The final result of this SQL query is ( this is tha same result that I need to get in SSAS cube ):

| Step | Sum of StepTimeinDays |
| --- | --- |
| 0_Start | 0 |
| 1_Material | 1 |
| 2_Saw | 1 |
| 3_Build | 2 |
| 4_Paint | 1 |
| 5_Varnish | 0 |
| 6_Packing | 1 |

For example, for the Total Percent measure I used the Expression below and works fine.

```
([Measures].[StepTimeinDays],[Process].[Step].CurrentMember)/([Measures].[StepTimeinDays],[Process].[Step].[All])
```

Now the same "table" are in a SSAS multidimensional cube, I'm trying to get the same result of SQL query in the SSAS expression field to create a measure without success.

I tried to use MDX expression and the more close that I have is below:

```
([Measures].[StepTimeinDays],[Process].[Step].[All],[Process].[Step].&[2_Saw])
```

But this is returning wrong value. Other expressions with parent returned syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved in another forum, but the measure could be created without curly braces to get set of data:

```
 sum ( NonEmpty ( [Product].[OperatorName].[OperatorName] * [Product].[ProductCode].[ProductCode], ([Measures].[StepTimeinDays], [Product].[Step].&[2_Saw]) ), [Measures].[StepTimeinDays] )
```